# I want to enable the textbox if the value of the radiobtnlist is 1

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have this code to disable the textbox if the value of RadioButtonList is zero. But it is not working I do not know why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
            $("#RadioButtonList1").change(function() {
              var st = ("#RadioButtonList1").val();
              if (("#RadioButtonList1").val() == "1") {
                   $("#TextBox_ArrivalDate").prop("disabled",false);
              }else{
                  $("#TextBox_ArrivalDate").prop("disabled",true);
              }
            );
       });

</script>
```

Here is my RadioButtonList

```xml
<asp:Label ID="type" Cssclass="label" runat="server" Text="Please Choose One"></asp:Label>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 47px" Width="153px">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Round Trip</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">One Way</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 0):

hopefully my snippet can help you in any ways. have a nice day!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $("[name=trip]").change(function() {
        var st = $("[name=trip]:checked").val();
        if (st == "1") {
          $("#TextBox_ArrivalDate").prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $("#TextBox_ArrivalDate").prop('disabled', true);
        }
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="trip" value="1" checked> roundtrip<br>
  <input type="radio" name="trip" value="0"> one way<br>
  <input type="text" id="TextBox_ArrivalDate">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it is still not working. this will disable the textbox if I choose either of the radio btn

Comment: hi, have you tried "run code snippet" button to see the result? it's actually working well, i actually use this snippet a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

change this line from

$("#RadioButtonList1").change(function()  to 
 $("<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>").change(function().

ASP.Net renders the RadioButton ID in a different format. You can access the id of the radiobutton on the clientside using this syntax.

Comment: do I have to change the syntax  for accessing the id for the textbox too?

Comment: Yes, For all Asp.Net controls, to perform operations on the clientside, Its always good to use ID.ClientID to access the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#RadioButtonList1 input').change(function () {
                    debugger;
                    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
                        $('#TextBox_ArrivalDate').attr("enabled", "enabled");
                    } else {
                        $('#TextBox_ArrivalDate').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }
                });
            });
```